# ODOO 10 custom report pdf name

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am developing a custom report in ODOO10 CE and I have a problem naming the generated PDF. It always names the "string" field in the report definition. It ignores the print_report_name field.

Here is the report definition:

```
<report
    id="action_report_as"
    model="report_as"
    string="Report AS_EE"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="report_as_ee.report_as"
    paperformat="report.vertical_1"
/>
<record
    id="action_report_as"
    model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="print_report_name">mycorrectreportname.pdf</field>
</record>
```

And here is the .py:

```
class ReportAs(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.report_as_ee.report_as'

@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    self.model = self.env.context.get('active_model')
    docs = self.env[self.model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
    as_records = []
    #
    # code that puts records in as_records array
    #
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': self.model,
        'docs': docs,
        'time': time,
        'as': as_records
    }
    return self.env['report'].render('report_as_ee.report_as', docargs)
```

Maybe I need to put the name from the .py? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you  can do it like this, go to Settings -> Technical ->reports ->reports, select the report of the sales,

Example, Report **Quotation / Order**. Then open the report and add
 **"((object.name or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"** this to field Printed Report Name.

Check with Quotation/Sale Order Print.

Thanks

Comment: Yes this works and I use it in a few reports. But in my custom report module this field are added correctly but always put the "string" field defined in the xml report definition as pdf name.

Comment: Can you Update the image for what you face?